# Wordpress array null

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a checkout system, within my Wordpress that shows me the following message:

> **Notice:** Undefined index: answers in
> /srv/www/vhosts/wordpress/wp-content/themes/../checkout/fragment-header.php
> on line 3
>
> **Notice:** Trying to access array offset on value of type null in
> /srv/www/vhosts/wordpress/wp-content/themes/../checkout/fragment-header.php
> on line 3

The php code of that file is the following:

```
<?php
$valorAccesorio = $args['quote']['answers']['vehicleGncValue'] ?? '0';
$cuotaMensual = $args['quote']['answers']['planPremioMensual'] + 
(isset($args['quote']['answers']['apPremioMensual']) ? $args['quote']['answers']['apPremioMensual'] : 0);
?>

<header id="header">
<div class="wrap menu-wrap">
<?php
  $class = (theme_get_custom_logo()) ? 'image' : 'text';
  echo '<h1 class="site-title ' . $class . '">';
  echo '<a href="' . esc_url(home_url('/')) . '" rel="home">';
  if (theme_get_custom_logo()) echo '<img src="' . theme_get_custom_logo() . '" class="site-logo" alt="' . htmlspecialchars(get_bloginfo('name')) . '" />';
  echo '<strong>' . get_bloginfo('name') . '</strong>';
  echo '</a>';
  echo '</h1>';
?>

<div class="right-section">
  <?php if ($args['quote']['product'] == 'seguro-de-motos' || $args['quote']['product'] == 'seguro-de-autos-y-pick-ups') : ?>
    <h1>
      Estás contratando un plan
      <span><?php echo $args['quote']['answers']['planCobertura'] ?></span>,
      para tu
      <span>
        <?php echo $args['quote']['answers']['vehicleBrand'] ?>
        <?php if (isset($args['quote']['answers']['vehicleModel'])) {
          echo $args['quote']['answers']['vehicleModel'];
        } else {
          echo $args['quote']['answers']['vehicleVersion'];
        } ?>
        <?php echo $args['quote']['answers']['vehicleYear'] ?>
      </span>
    </h1>
    <p>
      Suma asegurada: $<?php echo number_format(($args['quote']['answers']['vehicleValue'] + $valorAccesorio), 2, ',', '.') ?>
      |
      Cuota mensual: $<?php echo number_format(($cuotaMensual), 2, ',', '.') ?>
    </p>
  <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

From what I understand I am generating an array with null value, but I do not understand how to generate it by another way

Some help? Thanks!

Comment: You are trying to access array with non existing index. Where are you setting `$args` array in the code ? @Mario

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)